# Change height of footer in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to reduce the height of the page footer on an SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) Report less than .88597in?

I tried to set the `height` to `.5` in the properties panel and right-clicking the footer, selecting footer properties then putting `.5` in the height box. Neither work.

Comment: You can set the footer height to whatever you want. Make sure there is noting in the footer that is forcing it to grow, you can only set it's height to the lowest value that will allow all the objects in the footer to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you. I pulled everything out of the footer, adjusted the size and put everything back in. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report footer is not restricted to it's height. You either have a textbox/image/rectangle with a larger height, or a textbox within is causing a line break.

Try setting the textboxes properties within the footer to `CanGrow: false` and `CanShrink:true` to make sure these don't increase the height. 
Also check that none of your objects in the footer have a dynamic location/position or size.

Comment: Did you even read my answer? Besides the fact that the footer has no CanGrow property, I advised for changing this property for textboxes. Read properly before commenting

Answer (score 1):

If it is an RDLC file, then you can only change the height when it is empty. Cut the objects in the footer, resize it, and then paste them back in.